# Evaluating Models that Return Percentage Present of Multiple Classes

Tags: model-evaluations

If there is a model that returns a vector of the amount of different classes present in the data as percentages, what would be a good way to evaluate it (with charts and/or statistics)?

Say, for example, that a batch of pond water contains 30% Bacteria1 and 70% Bacteria2 (data is [0.3, 0.7]. Our model returns 35% Bacteria1 and 65% Bacteria2 (output is [0.35, 0.65]). How would we evaluate the accuracy of this model?

Am I right in thinking that we can't use things like confusion matrices or ROC/AUC curves because this isn't a classification problem? I'm not sure if there exist other metrics like these ones for this kind of problem though.

Comment: How do you fit the model?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about that part yet, some approaches I've thought for my application are fingerprinting or creating a tree-based ML model, but I just wanted to figure out how to evaluate it first before creating the model itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you're asking about the case where the model predicts a probability distribution or similar.

Assuming one has a test set with the true distribution for every instance, I think the most direct way to evaluate such a model is with a distance/similarity measure between distributions, for example [KL divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) or [Bhattacharyya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhattacharyya_distance). The distance is calculated between the predicted and true distribution for every instance, then the value is aggregated across instances (typically taking the mean).

You're correct that this is not classification, so classification evaluation techniques wouldn't apply (unless one is interested only in which class has the highest predicted probability in the distribution).